# Change JPA Entities Id Generation Streategy

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

There is a JSF/JPA application with EclipseLink2 which has about 40 different Entity classes. The method used to generate the id for every Entity class is AUTO.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;
```

After about one weeks run in production, the Id numbers has passed more than 10,000. I am worries about the possibility of running out the long numbers in few years time.

So I searched the net and changed the Id Generation Strategy as below.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "item_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "item_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName = "ITEM_ENTITY_SEQ")
Long id;
```

But when a new Entity is been created, there is an error as follows.

How can I change the auto generation strategy so that there will be no threat to running out of long ids after the development stage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The largest possible long value is 2^63-1, so if your database generated 1,000,000 (1 million!) IDs per second, you would get an overflow in more than 290,000 years.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I could not stop laughing after reading comment by isnot2bad.

Comment: I am sorry that I could not paste the error. I changed back to previous method as it is practically not possible to run out of generated Ids as isnot2bad stated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As isnot2bad stated in the comment, it is practically impossible to run out if auto-generated ids and I have given up the new method of generating seperate Ids.

Comment: So if your question is answered with that, mark it as answered :)